# Error exporting activities: Unknown column 'activity_priority.label' in 'field list'

Tags: activities, export

I upgraded a site last night from 4.7.13 to 4.7.27, and there's now an error when exporting activites. The error is:

Unknown column 'activity_priority.label' in 'field list']"]

I see where this part of the query is built in the civicrm/CRM/activity/BAO/Query.php file, and indeed there is no activity_priority table in my database.

I'm unable to reproduce the error in a Civi demo, so I'm wondering if its something specific to my local installation.

Is there supposed to be an activity_priority table? If so, how would it be created?

If not, any ideas on what would cause this issue?

EDIT: Here is the entire query:

```
SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type  as `contact_type`, contact_a.contact_sub_type  as `contact_sub_type`, contact_a.sort_name  as `sort_name`, contact_a.display_name  as `display_name`, contact_a.do_not_email  as `do_not_email`, contact_a.do_not_phone  as `do_not_phone`, contact_a.do_not_mail  as `do_not_mail`, contact_a.do_not_sms  as `do_not_sms`, contact_a.do_not_trade  as `do_not_trade`, contact_a.is_opt_out  as `is_opt_out`, contact_a.legal_identifier  as `legal_identifier`, contact_a.external_identifier  as `external_identifier`, contact_a.nick_name  as `nick_name`, contact_a.legal_name  as `legal_name`, contact_a.image_URL  as `image_URL`, contact_a.preferred_communication_method  as `preferred_communication_method`, contact_a.preferred_language  as `preferred_language`, contact_a.preferred_mail_format  as `preferred_mail_format`, contact_a.hash  as `hash`, contact_a.source  as `contact_source`, contact_a.first_name  as `first_name`, contact_a.middle_name  as `middle_name`, contact_a.last_name  as `last_name`, contact_a.prefix_id  as `prefix_id`, contact_a.suffix_id  as `suffix_id`, contact_a.formal_title  as `formal_title`, contact_a.communication_style_id  as `communication_style_id`, contact_a.job_title  as `job_title`, contact_a.gender_id  as `gender_id`, contact_a.birth_date  as `birth_date`, contact_a.is_deceased  as `is_deceased`, contact_a.deceased_date  as `deceased_date`, contact_a.household_name  as `household_name`, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', NULL, contact_a.organization_name ) as organization_name, contact_a.sic_code  as `sic_code`, contact_a.user_unique_id  as `user_unique_id`, contact_a.employer_id  as `current_employer_id`, contact_a.is_deleted  as `contact_is_deleted`, contact_a.created_date  as `created_date`, contact_a.modified_date  as `modified_date`, contact_a.addressee_id as addressee_id, contact_a.addressee_display as addressee_display, contact_a.addressee_custom as addressee_custom, contact_a.email_greeting_id as email_greeting_id, contact_a.email_greeting_display as email_greeting_display, contact_a.email_greeting_custom as email_greeting_custom, contact_a.postal_greeting_id as postal_greeting_id, contact_a.postal_greeting_display as postal_greeting_display, contact_a.postal_greeting_custom as postal_greeting_custom, IF ( contact_a.contact_type = 'Individual', contact_a.organization_name, NULL ) as current_employer, civicrm_address.id as address_id, civicrm_location_type.id as location_type_id, civicrm_location_type.name as `location_type`, civicrm_address.street_address as `street_address`, civicrm_address.street_number as `street_number`, civicrm_address.street_number_suffix as `street_number_suffix`, civicrm_address.street_name as `street_name`, civicrm_address.street_unit as `street_unit`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_1 as `supplemental_address_1`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_2 as `supplemental_address_2`, civicrm_address.supplemental_address_3 as `supplemental_address_3`, civicrm_address.city as `city`, civicrm_address.postal_code_suffix as `postal_code_suffix`, civicrm_address.postal_code as `postal_code`, civicrm_address.geo_code_1 as `geo_code_1`, civicrm_address.geo_code_2 as `geo_code_2`, civicrm_address.name as `address_name`, civicrm_address.master_id as `master_id`, civicrm_address.county_id as county_id, civicrm_address.state_province_id as state_province_id, civicrm_address.country_id as country_id, civicrm_phone.id as phone_id, civicrm_phone.phone_type_id as phone_type_id, civicrm_phone.phone as `phone`, civicrm_phone.phone_ext as `phone_ext`, civicrm_email.id as email_id, civicrm_email.email as `email`, civicrm_email.on_hold as `on_hold`, civicrm_email.is_bulkmail as `is_bulkmail`, civicrm_email.signature_text as `signature_text`, civicrm_email.signature_html as `signature_html`, civicrm_im.id as im_id, civicrm_im.provider_id as `im_provider`, civicrm_im.provider_id as provider_id, civicrm_im.name as `im`, civicrm_openid.id as openid_id, civicrm_openid.openid as `openid`, civicrm_worldregion.id as worldregion_id, civicrm_worldregion.name as `world_region`, civicrm_website.id as website_id, civicrm_website.url as `url`, civicrm_activity.id as activity_id, activity_type.value as activity_type_id, activity_type.label as activity_type, civicrm_activity.subject as activity_subject, civicrm_activity.activity_date_time as activity_date_time, activity_status.label as activity_status,
  civicrm_activity.status_id as status_id, civicrm_activity.duration as activity_duration, civicrm_activity.location as activity_location, civicrm_activity.details as activity_details, civicrm_activity.source_record_id as source_record_id, civicrm_activity.is_test as activity_is_test, civicrm_activity.campaign_id as activity_campaign_id, civicrm_activity.engagement_level as activity_engagement_level, source_contact.sort_name as source_contact, activity_priority.label as activity_priority,
  civicrm_activity.priority_id as priority_id  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a LEFT JOIN civicrm_address ON ( contact_a.id = civicrm_address.contact_id AND civicrm_address.is_primary = 1 ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_email ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_email.contact_id AND civicrm_email.is_primary = 1)  LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_phone.contact_id AND civicrm_phone.is_primary = 1)  LEFT JOIN civicrm_im ON (contact_a.id = civicrm_im.contact_id AND civicrm_im.is_primary = 1)  LEFT JOIN civicrm_openid ON ( civicrm_openid.contact_id = contact_a.id AND civicrm_openid.is_primary = 1 ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_location_type ON civicrm_address.location_type_id = civicrm_location_type.id  LEFT JOIN civicrm_country ON civicrm_address.country_id = civicrm_country.id  LEFT JOIN civicrm_worldregion ON civicrm_country.region_id = civicrm_worldregion.id  LEFT JOIN civicrm_activity_contact
                  ON ( civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id = contact_a.id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_activity
                  ON ( civicrm_activity.id = civicrm_activity_contact.activity_id
                  AND civicrm_activity.is_deleted = 0 AND civicrm_activity.is_current_revision = 1 ) INNER JOIN civicrm_contact
                  ON ( civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id and civicrm_contact.is_deleted != 1 ) LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group option_group_activity_status ON (option_group_activity_status.name = 'activity_status') LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value activity_status ON (civicrm_activity.status_id = activity_status.value
                           AND option_group_activity_status.id = activity_status.option_group_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group option_group_activity_type ON (option_group_activity_type.name = 'activity_type') LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value activity_type ON (civicrm_activity.activity_type_id = activity_type.value
                           AND option_group_activity_type.id = activity_type.option_group_id )  LEFT JOIN civicrm_website ON contact_a.id = civicrm_website.contact_id LEFT JOIN civicrm_activity AS parent_id ON civicrm_activity.id = parent_id.parent_id
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_activity_contact ac
                  ON ( ac.activity_id = civicrm_activity_contact.activity_id AND ac.record_type_id = 2)
    INNER JOIN civicrm_contact source_contact ON (ac.contact_id = source_contact.id) WHERE  (  (  (  ( contact_a.sort_name LIKE '%smith%' ) OR  ( civicrm_email.email LIKE '%smith%' )  )  )  )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0) AND  civicrm_activity.id IN ( 25008,25006,25005,25004,25002,25001,24999,24997,24995,24993,24992,24991,24989,24987,24986,24985,24984,24982,24981,24979,24978,24976,24975,24974,24973,24971,24970,24968,24967,24965,24964,24962,24960,24959,24958,24957,24956,24954,24952,24953,24951,24949,24947,25003,25000,24899,24945,24998,24996,24990 )  AND contact_a.is_deleted != 1  GROUP BY civicrm_activity.id  LIMIT 0, 100000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing your SQL to the code, there's certainly a bug, but I can't replicate it on my end.  The `select` method understands that the priority should be included; the `from` method does not.  I don't think this is easily solved without a live debugger.

As a workaround, I'm 95% sure that this error won't occur if you explicitly select the fields to export (instead of exporting "primary fields".  It's tedious, but easily tested by just exporting 1-2 fields plus the priority field.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found the source of the issue -- the code for this functionality had been overwritten in civicrm_php, and I neglected to look there to update code when upgrading civi. So, not a civi issue at all.